# Fetching data dynamically in Collections

Tags: oracle

I need to use collections as below, but want to print the output dynamically instead of specifying PL01, PL02, PL03...as this is going to be bigger list. If not possible using RECORD type, how can this be achieved using collections.

Business scenario : Having a item price list in an excel sheet as price list code in the first row (each column refers to a price list) and different items in each row. The number of price list and the items will differ every time. Now i need to populate this excel in collections in same format (Table with items in rows and price list code as columns) and use it to update the correct price list.

```
DECLARE    
  TYPE RT IS RECORD (ITEM  VARCHAR2(20),
                     PL01  NUMBER,
                     PL02  NUMBER,
                     PL03  NUMBER,
                     PL04  NUMBER,
                     PL05  NUMBER);    
  TYPE TT IS TABLE OF RT;    
  MY_REC RT;
  MY_TAB TT := TT();    
BEGIN
  MY_TAB.EXTEND;

  MY_TAB(1).ITEM := 'ABC';
  MY_TAB(1).PL01 := '40';
  MY_TAB(1).PL02 := '42';
  MY_TAB(1).PL03 := '44';
  MY_TAB(1).PL04 := '46';
  MY_TAB(1).PL05 := '48';

  MY_TAB.EXTEND;

  MY_TAB(2).ITEM := 'DEF';
  MY_TAB(2).PL01 := '60';
  MY_TAB(2).PL02 := '62';
  MY_TAB(2).PL03 := '64';
  MY_TAB(2).PL04 := '66';
  MY_TAB(2).PL05 := '68';   

  FOR I IN 1..2
  LOOP
    Dbms_Output.PUT_LINE(MY_TAB(I).ITEM||' - '||MY_TAB(I).PL01||' - '||MY_TAB(I).PL02||' - '||
                         MY_TAB(I).PL03||' - '||MY_TAB(I).PL04||' - '||MY_TAB(I).PL05);
  END LOOP;

END;
/
```

Comment: From your comments to the responders it seems the business logic you're trying to implement is rather complicated (not to say peculiar). You should **edit your question** to explain more about what you're trying to achieve (and why it has to be done this way).

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create `TYPE` as objects and using a `TABLE` function to display by passing a `REFCURSOR`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE RT AS OBJECT ( ITEM  VARCHAR2(20),
                     PL01  NUMBER,
                     PL02  NUMBER,
                     PL03  NUMBER,
                     PL04  NUMBER,
                     PL05  NUMBER
                     );
                     /

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TT AS TABLE OF RT;  
/
```

---

```
VARIABLE x REFCURSOR;

DECLARE    
  MY_TAB TT := TT();    
BEGIN

  MY_TAB.EXTEND(2); --allocate 2 elements

  MY_TAB(1) := RT ( 'ABC',40,42,44,46,48);--you can assign all once/index
  MY_TAB(2) := RT ( 'DEF',60,62,64,66,68);

  OPEN :x FOR SELECT * FROM TABLE(MY_TAB);

END;
/
```

---

```
PRINT x
ITEM                       PL01       PL02       PL03       PL04       PL05
-------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
ABC                          40         42         44         46         48
DEF                          60         62         64         66         68
```

Comment: To be more specific, i need to read data like first row, third colum and then later second row, fifth column likewise.  How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a PL/SQL table inside the RECORD. Try this:

```
DECLARE
    TYPE PL_TABLE_TYPE IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
    TYPE RT IS RECORD (ITEM  VARCHAR2(20), PL_TABLE PL_TABLE_TYPE);
    TYPE TT IS TABLE OF RT;

    MY_TAB TT := TT();
BEGIN

    MY_TAB.EXTEND;
    MY_TAB(MY_TAB.LAST).ITEM := 'ABC';
    MY_TAB(MY_TAB.LAST).PL_TABLE := PL_TABLE_TYPE(40,42,33,46,48); 
    --> Why do you assign strings like '40' if you have a NUMBER data type?

    MY_TAB.EXTEND;
    MY_TAB(MY_TAB.LAST).ITEM := 'DEF';
    MY_TAB(MY_TAB.LAST).PL_TABLE := PL_TABLE_TYPE(60,62,64,66,68);

    FOR r IN MY_TAB.FIRST..MY_TAB.LAST LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(MY_TAB(r).ITEM || ' ');
        FOR i IN MY_TAB(r).PL_TABLE.FIRST..MY_TAB(r).PL_TABLE.LAST LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(MY_TAB(r).PL_TABLE(i) || ' ');
        END LOOP;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE;
    END LOOP;

END;
```

Comment: What am I trying to do now is, i have a excel sheet (With different number of rows and column every time) which i need to upload into a dynamically created temporary table (With same number of column and with excel first row as column names). This data will be validated for various business rules and used to update other data.  Now am trying to achieve this functionality using collections.  I will try the above solution and feedback. Thanks.

Comment: How can you apply business rules if the data structure is different every time?

Comment: Actually i want to do this through forms 6i, but nested collections is not supported. So am trying now in oracle 11.2 version but i get an error when i create RECORD type.

Comment: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "RECORD" when expecting one of   the following:  array varray table object fixed varying opaque sparse   The symbol "object was inserted before "RECORD" to continue.

Comment: I was attempting to create RECORD as a TYPE in schema directly, but it is not correct and that is why there was an error.  Instead i was asked to use OBJECT and it is created.  But Forms 6i is not supporting to have nested tables as well as schema level created used defined TYPE.  So i think i have to think away from collections to achieve my business scenario which is mentioned in the Post.  Any suggestion ?